# Writing a regular expression to find the name of failing tests

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regex against our logs to match the bold portion of the text below.

> stage\n[myenv-01] [Pipe] [MySearchTests] { (MySearchTests
> Tests)\n[myenv-01] [Pipe] [MySearchTests] tool\n[myenv-01]
> [MyPortalTests] \n[myenv-01] [MyPortalTests]
> Tests.MyPortal.MakeAWidgetTests > Validate WidgetUser@email.com is
> allowed to create a widget PASSED\n[myenv-01] [MyPortalTests]
> \n[myenv-01] [MyPortalTests] Tests.MyPortal.MakeAWidgetTests >
> Validate NonWidgetUser@email.com role is not allowed to create a
> widget STARTED\n Scanning
> widget-service/path/to/widget-service.jar...\n[myenv-01] [WidgetApp]
> \n[myenv-01] [WidgetApp] Tests.WidgetPortal.LoginTest **>
> loginWithWidgetUser FAILED\n**[myenv-01] [WidgetApp]
> Test.Waiting.WaitTimeoutException at WidgetSpec.groovy:30\n[myenv-01]
> [WidgetApp]

Here is my regular expression:

```
>\s(.*)\sFAILED\\n
```

It is currently matching the bolded text below.

> stage\n[myenv-01] [Pipe] [MySearchTests] { (MySearchTests
> Tests)\n[myenv-01] [Pipe] [MySearchTests] tool\n[myenv-01]
> [MyPortalTests] \n[myenv-01] [MyPortalTests]
> Tests.MyPortal.MakeAWidgetTests > Validate WidgetUser@email.com is
> allowed to create a widget PASSED\n[myenv-01] [MyPortalTests]
> \n[myenv-01] [MyPortalTests] Tests.MyPortal.MakeAWidgetTests **>
> Validate NonWidgetUser@email.com role is not allowed to create a
> widget STARTED\n Scanning
> widget-service/path/to/widget-service.jar...\n[myenv-01] [WidgetApp]
> \n[myenv-01] [WidgetApp] Tests.WidgetPortal.LoginTest >
> loginWithWidgetUser FAILED\n**[myenv-01] [WidgetApp]
> Test.Waiting.WaitTimeoutException at WidgetSpec.groovy:30\n[myenv-01]
> [WidgetApp]

How can I get it to match what I've bolded in the first text blob? It is matching too early right now. If it helps, the match can be disregarded if it finds the word `PASSED`. Basically I'm trying to regex the name of a failing test and we know those are between the greater than character `>` and the phrase `FAILED`. The blobs of text we look through are large, so the regex should be global.

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[^\][]*` (in C#, you do not need to escape the `]` inside, `[^][]*` will do). Most probably, you are testing against a string literal. In that case, remove `\\n` from your pattern in the C# code.

Comment: I'm removing the c# tag. It was a mistake. Sorry!

Comment: So, what is the language then? What is your *real* input string?

Comment: You can use this regex:  >\s\w+\sFAILED\\n (changed .* to \w+)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew we are writing the query in sumologic and it appears to match the syntax of the online editors I've tried including the one in the fiddle in my question

Comment: You have `>\s(.*)\sFAILED\\n` in the question and `\\n\[myenv-\d{1,2}\]\s\[[\w\.]*\]\s[\w\.].*\s>\s.*\sFAILED\\n` in the regex fiddle.

Comment: If your real string contains newlines, [`/>\s(.*)\sFAILED$/m` will work](https://regex101.com/r/Df3b5T/1). It is still not clear what input you have, if you have ``\`` + `n` char combinations there or newlines (LF symbols, coded in the string literal as `\n`)

Comment: Whoops. I've updated the fiddle to a new link. The real string does contain \n character literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to replace the `.` in your current regex with a character class that *definitely* contains anything that might be in a test name, but excludes any characters that are not likely to be in the name.

You have many options, all of which work equally well on the input you gave. Based on your experience with the rest of the logs, use your judgement on which one is best.

`>\s(\S+)\sFAILED\\n` will match any test name that doesn't contain whitespace, but *might* match more than you want if any test name is delimited by anything other than whitespace.

`>\s((?:(?!\\n).)*)\sFAILED\\n` will match any test name that doesn't contain newlines, but *might* match more than you want if any line includes multiple `>` characters.

`>\s(\w+)\sFAILED\\n` will match any test name that consists only of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`, but will match less than you want if any test names contain other characters.

`>\s([^>]+)\sFAILED\\n` will match everything between `>` and `FAILED`, which *might* be more than you want.